# In Netbeans, is there any way to compile on save when modifying a java file?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am used to Eclipse, in that when I save a file, it automatically generates the class file, so that when I run my application the change is already there.

Netbeans seems to be different unfortunately. Everytime I do a little change (and want to see that change), I have to go up to Run-->Clean And Build Project, then find my Java file and select 'Run File'.

Is there any way in Netbeans to speed up this process?

Comment: In fact, Netbeans also compiles while you save a file. Looks like your current installation have this option disabled.

Comment: By default netbeans automatically generates everything needed to run it within netbeans automatically. It's only if you need the external jar that you need to clean and build

Comment: And IMO, when you're working with larger projects, it is better to compile on demand than on each file save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: you don't need "Clean and build project" each time.

Just use "Run project" (or "Run Main Project") and NetBeans will take care of compiling whatever needs compiling.

But if you do want the "Compile on Save" feature you can enable that in the project's properties under the "Build -> Compiling" options:

[image]

Comment: hmmm weirdly my Compile on Save option is grayed out.

Comment: @OliverWatkins: what kind of project do you use? Ant based? Maven? Freeform?

Comment: agree with you about setting the main class. Thats much simpler. (Still havent figured out why its graying out though)

Comment: @OliverWatkins: maybe a combination of project type (JavaEE, JavaSE) together with the JDK and NetBeans version.

Answer (score 0):

For more details on Compile-On-Save see the official FAQ page http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to mention in case it helps anyone, that for my "Maven Web Application" project, every time I checked "Compile On Save" and clicked OK, it would not save it. I would reopen the Project Properties to find it unselected. As it turns out the reason was that the nb-configuration.xml for the project was made read-only from source control.